# If $A + tB$ is similar to $A$ for infinitely many values of $t$, where $A$ is diagonalizable, is $B$ necessarily equal to $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I came across a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878039/if-atb-is-nilpotent-for-n1-distinct-values-of-t-then-a-and-b-are-nilpotent), which should guarantee that $B$ is nilpotent, but I wonder if knowing that the matrices are similar (not just having the same eigenvalues) is enough to conclude that $B = 0$. I'm particularly interested in the case where $A$ is diagonalizable, but I would not be surprised if that isn't relevant here.

I considered using the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition to show that $B = 0$ since if $A = P(A + tB)P^{-1}$ for $t \neq 0$, we have $A = A + 0$ as well as $A = PAP^{-1} + tPBP^{-1}$, where $A$ and $PAP^{-1}$ are diagonalizable and $0$ and $tPBP^{-1}$ are nilpotent. However, I don't know that $A$ and $B$ commute, so this decomposition is not necessarily unique. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No. E.g. $A+tB=\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&0}$ is similar to $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ for all $t$ and the latter is diagonalisable (because it has two distinct eigenvalues).

Answer (score 7):

For the non-diagonalizable case, take
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For all $t$ except $t=-1$, we have $A+tB$ similar to $A$.